# Not able to get non zero location if the UITapGestureRecognizer is installed at top level UIWindow keyWindow

Tags: ios, swift

The following code able to detect tap location

### Able to detect tap location

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
    
    @objc func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view)
        print("location \(location)")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

However, we want to detection done on the top level Window, globally, without tied to a single view controller's view.

---

### Not able to detect tap location

```
extension UIWindow {
    static var key: UIWindow! {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
    
    @objc func tap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view)
        print("location \(location)")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        UIWindow.key.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Doesn't matter where do you tap, we always get

```
location (0.0, 0.0)
location (0.0, 0.0)
```

---

Does anyone know why it is so, and how can we resolve such? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why passing the window to `location(in:)` always gives you (0, 0). This is as if the window is not in the same view hierarchy, as if you did `location(in: UIView())`.

Anyway, note that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-location) says that you should pass `nil` to `location(in:)` to indicate that you want the location in the coordinate system of the window:

> **Parameters**
>
> - `view`
>
>   A `UIView` object on which the gesture took place. Specify `nil` to indicate the window.

I suppose this *could* be interpreted as "you should *not* pass the window to `location(in:)`, use `nil` to do that instead".

This works:

```
let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: nil)
print("location \(location)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need a view to add the gesture to , Replace

```
UIWindow.key.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

with

```
UIWindow.key.subviews.last?.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```